# ngIf condition to get ride of redundant value

Tags: angular

I have a `div` that display dates I want to hide and only show the recent date

```html
    <div class="users" *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
            <div *ngIf="user.recipient === selectedUser._id && showUser(user)">
                <div class="user-date">
                  {{ user.date | date:'EEEE'}} {{user.date | date:'d'}} {{ user.date | date:'MMMM'}} {{ user.date |
                  date:'yyyy'}}
              </div>
    <div>
```

At the moment I'm displaying it like this:

```typescript
["Mon Jul 16 2018 11:40:28 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:33:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:21:36 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:03:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:01:05 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 08:53:23 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 08:52:33 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:49 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)"]
```

And what I want to achieve is to do an `ngFor` so I can only get it like this :

```typescript
   [ "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
    "Mon Jul 16 2018 11:40:28 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
     "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:33:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)"]
```

This will display the most recent date of the days

A stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stacktest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ritaj https://stackblitz.com/edit/stacktest sorry

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this would be to perform the filtering in your component.

// Component

```
public getMostRecentDatesPerDay() {
  const results = {};
  this.users.forEach(user => {
    const key = (new Date(user.date.getFullYear(), user.date.getMonth(), user.date.getDate())).toString();
    const existingDate = results[key];
    if (existingDate === undefined || existingDate < user.date) {
      results[key] = user.date;
    }
  });
  return Object.values(results);
}
```

// HTML

```
<div class="users" *ngFor="let user of getMostRecentDatesPerDay(); let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
  <div *ngIf="user.recipient === selectedUser._id && showUser(user)">
    <div class="user-date">
      {{ user.date | date:'EEEE'}} {{user.date | date:'d'}} {{ user.date | date:'MMMM'}} {{ user.date | date:'yyyy'}}
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

---

Explanation / Notes:

The function works by determining the unique `key` value as a date with no time component. Then, it compares the existing value so that the unique value is set to the latest value for that day.

NOTE: This would be much easier with [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), I highly recommend you look into this library if you do a lot of date logic.

WARNING: If the users array is large, this may have an impact on performance. When binding to a function in the HTML, the function is re-evaluated on EVERY change detection pass. If this is a problem, you should run the function at setup or whenever the `users` array changes and then store the result into a component field.

---

No Component? No Problem!

[Reference Tutorial](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-pipes-angular/)

```
// Custom Pipe

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'uniqueByDate'})
export class UniqueByDate implements PipeTransform {
  transform(values: { date: Date }[]): string {
    const results = {};
    values.forEach(value => {
      const key = (new Date(value.date.getFullYear(), value.date.getMonth(), value.date.getDate())).toString();
      const existingDate = results[key];
      if (existingDate === undefined || existingDate < value.date) {
        results[key] = user.date;
      }
    });
    return Object.values(results);
  }
}
```

// HTML

```
<div class="users" *ngFor="let user of users | uniqueByDate; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
  <div *ngIf="user.recipient === selectedUser._id && showUser(user)">
    <div class="user-date">
      {{ user.date | date:'EEEE'}} {{user.date | date:'d'}} {{ user.date | date:'MMMM'}} {{ user.date | date:'yyyy'}}
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Previous explanation / notes still apply

Comment: Sorry sir i tried to do it through a component, but i can't because i get a data from the database and i'm using GraphQl. 
That's why i want to find a solution through the HTML

Comment: @LisaParker I don't understand your statement. The data is stored into the `users` field on the component, right?

Comment: @LisaParker If you really truly can't use a component at all, then your best bet is going to be creating a custom pipe (that I will add to my answer when I can)

Comment: Tried to implement your solution the first one, it's saying type "Date" cannot be used as an index type ===>const existingDate = results[key];

Comment: @LisaParker Ah dammit. Updated to use `.toString` on it.

Comment: Awesome last but not least , return Object.values(results); is throwing Property values does not exist on type ObjectConstructor

Comment: Sorry Sir, that's what i get now user.date.getFullYear is not a function

Comment: @LisaParker Huh, that's odd. Object.values is well supported (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), but you could replace that with `Object.keys(a).map(key => a[key])` for the same effect in IE.
The getFullYear is strange to me, since that has full support (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), so I think I may have misunderstood the object type. As noted by the type annotation, I assumed this was a `Date` object. If it's not, you could convert it or adjust this approach. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Pipe` to do that:

**Example 01:** ( If you are using just `dates: string[]` like in your <kbd>[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stacktest?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)</kbd> )

Implement a `Pipe` like below:

```typescript
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
@Pipe({
  name: 'dateFilter'
})
export class DateFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let diplayDates: any[] = []
    let datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
    let filteredDateTimes = [];
    let filteredDates = [];

    value.forEach((date) => {    
      diplayDates.push(new Date(date));
    });

    let sortDates = diplayDates.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      let date1: any = new Date(b);
      let date2: any = new Date(a);
      return date1 - date2;
    });

    sortDates.forEach((date) => {
      let day = datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      let index = filteredDates.indexOf(day);
      if (index === -1) {
        filteredDates.push(day);
        filteredDateTimes.push(date);
      }
    });

    return filteredDateTimes;
  }

}
```

Apply it in your HTML like below:

```html
<div *ngFor="let date of dates | dateFilter ; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
  {{date | date:'EEEE'}} {{date | date:'d'}}  {{ date | date:'MMMM'}} {{ date |date:'yyyy'}}
</div>
```

<kbd>[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stacktest-sugbb8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)</kbd>

---

**Example 02:** ( If you are using just `users` array like in your question )

Change your `Pipe` like this:

```typescript
 transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let diplayDates: any[] = []
    let datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
    let filteredDateTimes = [];
    let filteredDates = [];

    value.forEach((user) => {
      user.date = new Date(user.date)
      diplayDates.push(user);
    });

    let sortDates = diplayDates.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      let date1: any = new Date(b.date);
      let date2: any = new Date(a.date);
      return date1 - date2;
    });


    sortDates.forEach((user) => {
      let day = datePipe.transform(user.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      let index = filteredDates.indexOf(day);
      if (index === -1) {
        filteredDates.push(day);
        filteredDateTimes.push(user);
      }
    });

    return filteredDateTimes;
  }
```

And use that `Pipe` in HTML like this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let user of users | dateFilter ; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
  {{user.date | date:'EEEE'}} {{user.date | date:'d'}}  {{ user.date | date:'MMMM'}} {{ user.date |date:'yyyy'}}
</div>
```

<kbd>[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stacktest-z7j678?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-filter.pipe.ts)</kbd>

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you sir for your response, so i have already a class, is it possible to implement this in the class that i already have  in my component ?

Comment: Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'dateFilter' could not be found ( i'm getting this error

Comment: add that filter into `declarations` of your `app.module.ts` like this `declarations: [DateFilterPipe ]` you can refer demo also

Comment: @LisaParker I updated my answer because  your are using  `users` array in actual implementation see it again. let me know if it work

Comment: Hello sir , i followed your suggestion i got  InvalidPipeArgument: 'Invalid Date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Comment: @LisaParker i think you have followed the first example. did you follow my second example ? it is matched with your requirement. and it should work and also see the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stacktest-z7j678?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-filter.pipe.ts).  let me know if it work for you

Comment: @LisaParker did you have any trouble with my second example [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stacktest-z7j678?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-filter.pipe.ts) ?

Comment: @LisaParker  if you find this answer helpful to you, could you please accept this as a correct answer? it would help others as well :)